# Delphi: how to make procedure on click on button array?

Tags: image, delphi, button, click, procedure

I have to make project in Delphi. I made an array of buttons and an array of images. I want to show Image[i] when I click button[i].

Can somebody help please?

Comment: What do you not know how to do? Do you know how to make an array, for example? Show your code so far so that we know what level of understanding you have.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the button's tag property to store a pointer to the correlating image. I'm unsure of your Array structure but here's a code snippet to demonstrate.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  Image1: TImage;
  Button2: TButton;
  Image2: TImage;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

private
  FMyCurrentImage : TImage; //Keeps track of the current image
  procedure MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
public

end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyCurrentImage := nil;

  Button1.Tag := Integer(Image1);
  Button1.OnClick := MyButtonClick;
  Image1.Hide;

  Button2.Tag := Integer(Image2);
  Button2.OnClick := MyButtonClick;
  Image2.Hide;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TButton then
    with Sender as TButton do
       if Assigned(TImage(Tag)) then
       begin
         //Hide the previously selected image
         if Assigned(FMyCurrentImage) then
           FMyCurrentImage.Hide;

         //Assign and show the clicked button's image
         FMyCurrentImage := TImage(Tag);
         FMyCurrentImage.Show;
       end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of component are you using in your form to show the image?

I don't know what you really need, but here's something I guess you'd want:

I have created three components in the form to test it: two TButton's and one of TImage type.

```
  TfrmTest = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    btn2: TButton;
    img: TImage;
    procedure showImage(sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;
```

In the `var` section:

```
var
  frmTest: TfrmTest;

  imagesArray: array[1..2] of String = ('blue.jpg', 'red.jpg');
  buttonsArray: array[1..2] of String = ('btn1', 'btn2');
```

The implementation of your event:

```
procedure TfrmTest.showImage(sender: TObject);
var
    i: integer;
begin
    for i := low(buttonsArray) to high(buttonsArray) do
    begin
        if (buttonsArray[i] = TButton(sender).name) then
        begin
            img.picture.loadFromFile('your images directory path here' + imagesArray[i]);
            break;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

In the **Object Inspector**, you need to set the `OnClick` event of your buttons with the `showImage` procedure.